# TSQL Aggregate function in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query

```
UPDATE [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE]
  SET [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].toplevelAccredCode = #PartnerLookupfinalForCode.Accreditation_Code
  FROM dbo.[P1_Log_FY14H1_CE]
  INNER JOIN #PartnerLookupfinalForCode
  ON [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].[Partner ID] = #PartnerLookupfinalforCode.Partner_ID
  WHERE [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].Intake_Date is not null and #PartnerLookupfinalforCode.[Rank]=(Select Min(Rank) from #PartnerLookupfinalforCode)
```

Here When updateing Toplevelaccredcode

I m getting results like this

```
[Partner ID] Code     Rank
A             silver    3
A             LessSilver 4
```

Here In log table partner A has unique record. I want Highest to be updated in log table.
Like for Partner A silver should be updated.
 Can any one correct my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT Partner_ID
    , Accreditation_Code
    , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Partner_ID ORDER BY [Rank]) [min_rank] 
    FROM #PartnerLookupfinalForCode)

UPDATE [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE]
SET [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].toplevelAccredCode = c.Accreditation_Code
FROM dbo.[P1_Log_FY14H1_CE]
INNER JOIN c ON [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].[Partner ID] = c.Partner_ID
    AND c.min_rank = 1
WHERE [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].Intake_Date is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE]
  SET [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].toplevelAccredCode = #PartnerLookupfinalForCode.Accreditation_Code
  FROM dbo.[P1_Log_FY14H1_CE]
  INNER JOIN #PartnerLookupfinalForCode
  ON [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].[Partner ID] = #PartnerLookupfinalforCode.Partner_ID
  INNER JOIN (Select Partner_ID,Code,Min(Rank) from #PartnerLookupfinalforCode Group By Partner_ID,Code)   MINPartner
  ON MINPartner.Partner_ID =#PartnerLookupfinalforCode.Partner_ID AND MINPartner.Code=#PartnerLookupfinalforCode.Code
  WHERE [P1_Log_FY14H1_CE].Intake_Date is not null
```